# 3D graphic in vector format

Tags: math-software, 3d

Please recommend a program that can build a graphic of a 3d function and save it to some vector file format (SVG, EPS/PostScript, WMF etc.) I found only Madagascar software, it is free, but it was made for Linux and to make it working with Windows I need to build/compile it, but I can not. :( There is no just a link to download a Windows version.

Are there any other software (preferably free or with a free trial period) to draw a 3d function in a vector format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) library for python - easy, free and powered by wonderful python!

Answer (score 1):

[Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) is an open-source program that [can draw 3D graphs of functions](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/3D%20graphs/index.html) and save them as "high-quality PostScript, PDF, SVG, or 3D PRC vector graphics". As of writing, they have installation binaries for Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows. However, it takes a little bit of programming to use (example [source](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/3D%20graphs/elevation.asy), [PDF result](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/3D%20graphs/elevation.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you. I tried Asymptote before. And it does create PostScript files, but those files just contain an embedded bitmap inside (PNG or JPG file). So, it is just a bitmap/raster file which is saved as a PostScript. But it is not a vector file.

True vector file is when it has commands like "LineTo, MoveTo, CurveTo", not just pixels.

Comment: Oh wow. Zooming in on the PDF I linked to, I see that it just contains a bitmap as well. That's rather misleading on their part!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend SketchUp, here is a link of many more programs:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_vector_graphics_editors

Comment: Thank you, but I need a software which can draw a graphic by function. Let's say I enter "z = x*y" and this program draws a 3d-graphic of this function. And then I need to save that result as a vector file. Not just a bitmap (not JPG, PNG).